# How to keep the python script running 24/7 and enter default value to Oracle DB if connection fails

Tags: python, database, oracle, modbus

I have a python script which collects data(solar,battery,load,currenttime) from my solar controller via modbus and writes the data onto my oracle DB. The current time is from my system time.  At the moment the code runs 24/7 (with  one minute interval)  and if the connection is lost the code tries 5 times to reconnect, and then stops executing.

My Goal :At the moment i have blank data as the script stops when connection is out. Is there a way i can keep the script running (even when there is no connection ) and put values like 0 into the solar and battery values and pass the current time regularly to the database so i can plot graphs based on 24 hours. And is there a way that my script can reconnect automatically as well? Thanks a lot for your precious time !!

Or is there a way to keep the script running even though there is no modbus connection. Then i can write if no connection input values 0 to battery and solar.

My code

```
from pymodbus.constants import Defaults
from pymodbus.constants import Endian
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient as ModbusClient
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
import schedule
import time


import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect("user/pas")  #connects to database
cursor = con.cursor()


Defaults.Timeout = 25
Defaults.Retries = 5

def loaddata():

  today = date.today()
  now = datetime.now()
  client = ModbusClient('10.8.0.14', port='83')

  result = client.read_input_registers(840, 2) # Read battery voltage

  trailerone = 1
   
  decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(result.registers, byteorder=Endian.Big)
  voltage=decoder.decode_16bit_uint()

  ####################### Battery voltage ####################################
  battery1 = str("{0:.1f}".format(voltage/10.0)) #battery1 has current battery voltage
 #############################################################################
  
  result2 = client.read_input_registers(776,3,unit=226)  # Read Solar data
  decoder2 = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(result2.registers, byteorder=Endian.Big)
  voltage2=decoder2.decode_16bit_uint()
  
#######################Solar voltage#####################################
  solar1 = str("{0:.1f}".format(voltage2/100.0)) # has solar voltage
##########################################################################
 

  result3 = client.read_input_registers(860, 1)  #Load Watts data
  decoder3 = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(result3.registers, byteorder=Endian.Big)
  voltage3=decoder3.decode_16bit_uint()
 
#########################LOAD, DATE , TIME #####################################
  load1 = str("{0:.1f} W".format(voltage3)) # has load wattage
 

  date1 = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") # has todays date
 

  current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S") # has current time
#################################################################################

  
  
  
##################### Inserting values into database table ####################
  
  cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Mytable(TRAILERID,PANELVOLTAGE,BATTERYVOLTAGE,DATADATE,DATATTIME) VALUES ( :trailerone,:solar1,:battery1,:date1, :current_time)',[trailerone,solar1,battery1,date1,current_time])

  con.commit()
  
  
  f.close()


schedule.every(60).seconds.do(loaddata)    #runs script every one minute endlessly 

while 1:
  schedule.run_pending()
  time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: On the Python side regarding connections, use a connection pool and do an acquire() and close() in the loop.  Read https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/ha.html.  If the connection goes down (for e.g. network outage), perhaps you can catch up and insert multiple records when the connection can be re-established. Regarding defaults, you may want to insert to a temp table, and use a DBMS_SCHEDULER job in the DB to read from that table and insert into your actual data table.  The job can insert default values if the Python script hasn't updated the temp table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone wondering how to do it. I have used the try and except method to implement what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`schedule.every(60).seconds.do(loaddata)`

Instead of using `schedule` lib, you should choose `cronjob` in Linux system.

Add `try...catch` around `loaddata`, When exception happen, save default 0 to solar.

Comment: thank you for answering, but is there a way to keep the script running rgardless if there is a connection to the tcp connection or not?

Comment: `cronjob` will re-init the connect every time. you need not warry about the connection.

Comment: @JCH Windows also got `Task Scheduler`

Comment: Yes, i will do it with the task scheduler, but since the connection error comes up everytime the script is run the values 0 cannot be enterd into the database  as the script stops :(  . I think i need to find a way that the script runs despite of any errors

Comment: @JCH Two methods here. 1: if you are using MySQL, create a event_schduler in db, set timestamp as an unique key, using `insert ingore` every minute to save default value. 2: do nothing, but when you plot, set to data to 0 as default value for every minute.